# ¿ Para que sirve static en C?

Tags: c

No entiendo muy bien para que sirve static en C, en un vídeo que estaba viendo en una lista de reproducción de YT dijo que servía para "privatizar una función", muchas gracias por todas vuestras respuestas.

Comment: Tiene diferente significado según aparezca fuera de una función (afecta a la visibilidad del símbolo, que es visible sólo dentro de ese fichero), o dentro de una función (afecta a dónde se almacena la variable, que lo hace en la zona de datos en lugar de la pila, lo que causa que la variable "sobreviva" entre diferentes ejecuciones de la función, "recordando" el valor que tenía en la ejecución anterior)

Comment: Aquí responden a tu misma pregunta, muy completo por cierto:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` cumple con dos funciones básicas dentro del lenguaje C:

1. Al usarlo sobre variables que están dentro de una función, permite que el valor de las mismas persista entre llamadas
2. Al usarlo sobre funciones o variables de ámbito global, garantiza que dicho elemento (variable o función) solo exista en la unidad de compilación en la que se encuentre declarado.

Dicho con ejemplos:

**Variable estática dentro de función**

```
void contador(void)
{
  static int var_estatica = 0;
  int var_no_estatica = 0;

  var_estatica++;
  var_no_estatica++;

  printf("%d %d\n", var_estatica, var_no_estatica);
}


for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  contador();
```

**Función estática**

`funciones.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int func_estatica()
{
  puts("func_estatica\n");
}

int func_no_estatica()
{
  puts("func_no_estatica\n");

  func_estatica(); // OK: Llamada dentro de la misma unidad de compilacion 
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
// Le decimos al compilador que esta funcion existe, pero que no esta aqui
// (ya la encontrara el enlazador)
extern func_no_estatica();

// Le decimos al compilador que esta funcion existe, pero que no esta aqui
// Como esta funcion esta marcada como static, no la va a encontrar
extern func_estatica();


int main()
{
  // Si se quita el comentario, el codigo no compila
  // func_estatica();

  func_no_estatica();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Los nombres de las funciones generan "simbolos" en los .o u .obj generados.

Esos simbolos pueden ser "publicos" o "privados". Por defecto son "publicos". Si pones "static" entoces es "privado".

Los simbolos "privados" no son visibles desde fuera del .o u .obj generado. Lo cual equivale a decir que no se pudede invocar "de forma normal" desde fuera del .o

Pero, OJO !!!, usando "punteros a funciones" y con funciones publicas que calculen y devuelvan el puntero a esa funcion privada, SI QUE ES INVOCABLE !!!.

Advanced:

- NO es invocable desde fuera con el linker (no va encontrar los simbolos en el proceso de linkado).
- SI es posible invocarla con punteros a funciones.

Es decir, NO confundir "simbolo privado" con "invocacion prohibida".

Answer (score 0):

Una funcion estatica restringe el llamado de la funcion al mismo documento en el que está declarada. En otras palabras solo la puedes llamar desde otras funciones que se encuentren en ese mismo archivo.